# How to produce an understadable vizual plot for time evolution from frequency of two variables

Tags: r

Having the results of a dataframe:

```
dframe <- structure(list(stock = c("Google, Yahoo", "Google", "Google, Yahoo", 
                                   "Google, Yahoo", "Amazon, Google", "Amazon, Google", "Amazon, Google"
), investor = c("Nathalie", "George", "Nathalie", "George", "Melanie", 
                "George", "Melanie"), year = c("2017", "2018", "2017", "2017", 
                                               "2018", "2018", "2017"), n = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                      "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 4
>   stock          investor year      n
>   <chr>          <chr>    <chr> <int>
> 1 Google, Yahoo  Nathalie 2017      2
> 2 Google         George   2018      1
> 3 Google, Yahoo  Nathalie 2017      2
> 4 Google, Yahoo  George   2017      1
> 5 Amazon, Google Melanie  2018      1
> 6 Amazon, Google George   2018      1
> 7 Amazon, Google Melanie  2017      1
> ```

Is there any friendly way to produce a time evolving plot (year column) which will show the frequency (column n) for matched pairs of stock-investor columns?

Comment: Are you looking for a stacked bar chart where one series is Nathalie-Google, one is Nathalie-Yahoo, etc. with Year on the x axis?

Comment: @JonSpring as you describe it I think yes it is the right option. Y axis will have the frq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
dframe %>%
  separate_rows(stock) %>%
  count(stock, investor, year, wt = sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, n, fill = interaction(investor, stock))) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]